My passphrase in Bitcoin Core is not recognised with parsing JSON error
I am currently in a bad situation, as I can't access my wallet on Bitcoin Core anymore. The wallet passphrase I have chosen does not seem to not work.
When I try it, I see the following message: "Error: Error parsing JSON:est"
I have the following characters in the passphrase:

spaces
/ character
letters with accent

Any help is appreciated as my savings are at stake :(

Are any of your backups of the wallet earlier than the passphrase?
